# Why the request result is different?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Help to newbie please. My head is broken.
I made mysql request in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'player' AND meta_value = 'yes'
```

and get

```
user_id

1

30

28

22

26

12
```

It is right result. And I run PHP script:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$sql_planet="SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'player' AND meta_value = 'yes'";
$result_planet = mysql_query($sql_planet);
while ($row_planet = mysql_fetch_object($result_planet)) {
    print_r($row_planet);
}
?>
```

and get

```
stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 108 ) stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 60 ) stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 48 ) stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 51 ) stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 7 ) stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 101 )
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Because you are using mysql_fetch_object() which returns result as object, use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead if you want to fetch associated array.

Comment: Stop using depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: I tryed assoc, but this two resultis is different again.

Comment: what results you are expecting? if you are referring to the set of user_ids then maybe you are connecting to two different mysql server/db

Comment: I expect that 'user_id' from php script will be the same as in the first request from phpmyadmin. I connect to the same db.

Comment: Double check if you are connecting to the same mysql server/db

Comment: I have only one server and db and can not connect to another db.

Answer (score 0):

I've redone your script with `mysqli`:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("your_server","your_user","your_pw","your_db");
if(!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql_planet="SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'player' AND meta_value = 'yes'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_planet);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "Id of user: ".row['user_id'];
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use mysqli_